# What is broad about this question?

Tags: discussion, closing

Recently I asked a [question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/359602/202341) about exclusivity of PS games as find it very confusing topic. However a day later it was closed with the reason "The question is too broad". And I'm not quite following why is this reason - I underlined in my question that exclusivity is a speculative topic and gave my definition of what it means for me, I provided reasoning behind willing this, outlined my own attempts to gain this knowledge and even explained what exactly wrong with it, giving a particular example of a mistake.

English is not my first language and I could misuse some terms making it confusing for everyone, but i just don't know what is wrong here.

**P.S.** I should admit that **answer** to this question may not exist, as I had hard time finding this out myself, but this should not be the reason for closing the question, as I merely look for community wisdom.

Answer (score 5):

Your question boiled down to:

> How in the world do people know if a game is exclusive?

Based on the body of your question, you are basically asking us to *present a practical model to differentiate between exclusive and non-exclusive games*.

As per the description of the closing reason, the question should be "*limited to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer*". **I think the reasoning behind this is that the scope of your question involves too many variables**.

**Apart from that, closing reasons are often limited in the sense that we can only use one**.
Another, and in my opinion better reason for which this question could have been closed, was that it involves developer intent: we simply cannot know whether or not it will be decided that games will be released on other platforms. Even most developers don't know in advance.

As one of the VTC'ers Timmy Jim already stated in a comment underneath your question:

> The *only way to know* if something will be exclusive or not is to pay attention to announcements made by the game creators. That's about it. Many games in the past have been exclusive to platforms but changes in the market have changed this.

So indeed we cannot know an answer, but please note that that is not the direct reason that it was closed - answerability does not (or: should not) penalize a question. (FYI: the developer intent closing reason exists because it often leads to unanswerability and conjecture, and thus might spark endless discussions, which are not appropriate for the Stackexchange platform.)

Comment: You are saying that it's not because nobody knows the answer and at the same the most likely reason is that "we simply cannot know the developer intent". I still can't see a reason for closing my question, better approach would be to give the answer explaining this

Comment: what are possible steps for me to make this question "answerable" and still relevant to what i'm looking for